# Can I use PUT http method with Python Bottle?

Tags: python, rest, bottle

I'm trying to do this:

```
@get("/admin/questions/:question_id")
def question (question_id):
    pass
    #Some code for returning the question

@put("/admin/questions/:question_id")
    pass
    #I intend to write some code to update the question here.
```

Is this possible? GET and POST do work, PUT is apparently not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. See the documentation:

- http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-request-methods
- http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.put

Example:

```
from bottle import put, run

@put("/foo")
def foo():
    return "Foo"

run()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this answers the question since OP already knows about the `put` method.

Answer (score 3):

I found this: https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/creating-a-rest-api-in-python-using-bottle-and-mongodb/. It might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same question. The above links were helpful.  I also found these webpages useful:

http://gotofritz.net/blog/weekly-challenge/restful-python-api-bottle/ (weekend code warrior creates restful interface in one page - this made it very clear for me)

http://www.marginhound.com/bottle-py-resources/
http://isbullsh.it/2011/11/Python-micro-frameworks/
http://publish.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html

Once I took the time to go through these pages, it was surprisingly easy to implement.

Comment: All links are dead except marginhound, which has no mention of PUT requests. Relevant, minimal code should be in the question itself for it to have lasting value.